# Why Coop doesn't control a pencil to communicate directly using gravity?

Tags: interstellar

In the movie Interstellar,

Coop uses the watch he gave to his daughter as a communication mean. He can do that since he masters gravity. He can also drop books to send Morse messages, etc. Gravity is the only thing that can swallow time. **If he's so skilled in gravity, why can't he use it to control forces applied to, let's say, a pencil, so he can write an understandable message on a sheet of paper?**

Controlling gravity means to nullify or increase it: by applying correct forces on both sides of the pen, **this should allow writing**

Comment: I don't think the spoiler tags are necessary given the nature of the question.

Comment: Isn't picking up some thing and using it by holding difficult by sending gravitational wave like force, that Coop used?

Comment: When was the last time anyone in the Nolan film did things the easy way?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Coop needs to send a message that is;

- **Sufficiently cryptic as to allow him to get to NASA**

but

- **Non-obvious who's sending the message**

and

- **Contains some sort of secondary message that Murph (and only Murph) can access years later**

Oh yeah...

- **and because the whole film is an enormous bootstrap paradox, he can't change the future because he didn't do it in the past.**

This is covered in more detail in the film's [official novelisation](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21488063-interstellar);

> “Cooper,” Tars said, “They didn’t bring us here to change the past.”
>   Of course they didn’t. Cooper paused, calming himself. No, he couldn’t change the past. But there was something else… something about what Tars was saying.
>   **They didn’t bring us here to change the past.**
>   They…
>   **“We brought ourselves here,”** he said, and he pushed off, found another angle, saw the room in a slightly different moment. It was full of dust from the storm, the storm that had come upon them at the baseball game. Murph had left her window open…
>   “Tars,” he said, studying the dust. “Feed me the coordinates of NASA in binary.”
>   And with his fingers, he traced the pattern, the lines he had found after the dust storm—

then

> “So what are we to do?” Tars asked.
>   **Cooper looked down the time dimension. The books? No, and not the lander. But the watch, on the shelf, as far as he could see…
>
>   “The watch,” he realized. “That’s it. She’ll come back for it.”**
>   “How do you know?” Tars asked.
>   And again he felt the certainty, a pull as strong as a black hole. Stronger—it was like the pull that had brought him here. That would bring Murph back, too.
>   “Because I gave it to her,” he said, excitement building. He scrutinized the watch for a moment. It would have to be simple, binary, or…
>   He had it.
>   “We use the second hand,” he told Tars. “Translate the data into Morse, and feed it to me.”

On top of that, as @VikramadityaMondal has pointed out in his comment, picking something up seems to a **very complex procedure** when he only has the ability to push & pull.

Comment: Is it he can not or unable to change the past because of bootstrap paradox or he thought that he was not there to change the past so 'lets not change it'?

Comment: Why the message has to be "Non-obvious who's sending the message"?  
In the end, she knows... if he sends the message and she reads it while he's already left home, why does it matter?  
  
+ writing it with a pen could be done without signing the message...  
"Sufficiently cryptic as to allow him to get to NASA"... writing coordinates on a sheet of paper would be much less hasardous than creating a binary message with dust.

Comment: @Evariste - Actually, at the end she states that she *personally* knows but that no-one else really believes her.

Comment: Accepting as answer, mostly because of the other answer provided in [Why didn't Cooper use his laptop?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86092/why-didnt-cooper-use-his-laptop), witch is accurate for this question as well.